# Batch create folder in input directory

Tags: batch-file

I want to have a batch file where I can specify a path such as 
C:\Users\Munch\Desktop\All Files\
and then it will create a folder within that specified directory.

Currently all it does is create folders on my desktop with the name Im providing in the input. For example, if enter in my input "All Files\Development" it will, on my desktop, create two folders named "All" and "Files"

```
@echo off
color 0C

:main
cls
echo =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
set /p dir=Enter directory:
echo =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
goto create
pause

:create

md "C:\Users\Munch\Desktop\%dir%\new"
pause
```

If I change my md line to

```
md "\%dir%\new"
```

and then enter in my batch input "C:\Users\Munch\Desktop\All Files", it still does the same.

Comment: The first variant worked fine for me. Try adding `@echo on` before `md` and check, how does line with `md` look like after variable substitution.

Comment: A path starting with a backslash at beginning is relative to root of current drive. You can see that by opening a command prompt window and run `dir /A \*` and you see all files and directories in root of current drive independent on which subdirectory is the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your path for the `md`/`mkdir` command is specified as "root-relative" - that is, you've got either the drive specification or a backslash as the first character of the path.

Instead, try omitting that, and use

```
@echo off
color 0C

:main
cls
echo =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
set /p dir=Enter directory:
echo =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
goto create
pause

:create

md "%dir%\new"
pause
```

*without* the leading `\` or `C:\...`.

The caveat with this is that if you do not supply a full path (starting with `\` or the root of a drive [`C:\`]), the new directory will be created in the relative path - that is, if you're in `C:\FOO`, and you invoke the batch file and enter `BAR\BAZ\QUUX` at the prompt, the folder that will be created will be `C:\FOO\BAR\BAZ\QUUX\NEW`. If you supply a drive but not the root of the drive (e.g., `D:BAR\BAZ\QUUX`), then the new folder will be created relative to whatever the current directory on that drive is (e.g., if the current directory on `D:` is `D:\YOTTA`, the folder created would be `D:\YOTTA\BAR\BAZ\QUUX\NEW`).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are apparently entering the quotes around the required directoryname.

In consequence, the actual command being executes is

```
md "C:\Users\Munch\Desktop\"All Files\Development"\new"
```

which is interpreted as md `"C:\Users\Munch\Desktop\"All`   `Files\Development"\new"`

so two directories are being created.

The really simple solution is to omit the quotes.

The programmatic solution, in case you forget, is to strip the quotes from `dir` within the `md` command.

```
md "U:\Users\Munch\Desktop\%dir:"=%\new"
```